# How to check that microphone is ready in use in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have media record and I need check for microphone is ready in use. Now, I can run default audio recorder and start my app. As the result, my app can't get access to mic and I can't catch this situation.

May be do you know some tricks for catch situation when mic is ready in use?

```
11-01 09:36:34.690: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'DRC Switch' cannot get 

element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.690: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Left Input PGA Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.690: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Right Input PGA Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.690: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Digital Capture Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.690: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'HPF Mode' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.790: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'DRC Switch' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.790: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Left Input PGA Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.790: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Right Input PGA Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.790: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'Digital Capture Volume' cannot get element info: -2
11-01 09:36:34.790: ERROR/NvAudioALSAControl(8901): Control 'HPF Mode' cannot get element info: -2
```

Comment: can you upload the code please ?

Comment: I got sample from official site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html for start.

Comment: Not at all! It says nothing. I've got only Error log message from NvAudioALSAControll only.

Comment: good, upload your error logs with question it will help to identify real problem.

Comment: This method must be called after setting up the desired audio and video sources, encoders, file format, etc., but before start(). If I understand right, It only checks settings, create a file and doesn't check status of mic.

Comment: one more question, are you running in Emulator or in real device ?

Comment: I don't use emulator, because of It's not serious. I use only real devices for test.

Comment: I've found some way, but I fink it's not correct. I read to buffer data and check. If all elements are 0 then mic is busy right now.